# How to switch views once user has authenticated

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm learning and try to get a firm grasp of correctly implementing sound MVC design.

I have a single window application managed by NSWindowController, with two view controllers for login (LoginViewController) and another view for once the user has logged in (MainViewController).

```
// MyWindowController.h
@interface MyWindowController : NSWindowController {
    IBOutlet NSView* myTargetView;

    LoginViewController *loginViewController;
    MainViewController *mainViewController;
}

- (void)changeViewController:(NSInterger)view;

@property (nonatomic, retain) LoginViewController *loginViewController;
```

Within MyWindowController's awakeFromNib method, I am detecting if the user is logged in or not via NSUserDefaults:

```
// MyWindowController.m
// pseudocode below
- (void)awakeFromNib
    IF the user is logged in
        set myTargetView to the view of MainViewController
    ELSE the user is not logged in
        set myTargetView to the view of LoginViewController
```

This works fine, then in my LoginViewController's view I have the following outlets and actions:

```
// LoginViewController.h
@interface LoginViewController : NSViewController {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *username;
    IBOutlet NSSecureTextField *password;
}


- (IBAction)authenticate:(id)sender;
```

And my authenticate method:

```
// LoginViewController.m
- (IBAction)authenticate:(id)sender

    ...

    IF (authenticated) {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"UserAuthenticated"];
    } ELSE {
        // Update loginView to display "Wrong username/password"
    }
```

My question is, once the user is authenticated and the user's defaults are updated to reflect such. How do I correctly command MyWindowController to swap to the MainViewController?

I'm learning towards KVO within MyWindowController to detech if the key:UserAuthenticated is true or not and if so swap in the main view. However I am unsure if this is the correct approach.

If my application design is fatally wrong, please correct and explain to me why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a delegate, but that is inflexible and not optimal design. Notifications would be OK, though they can make it hard to trace what's going on as your project grows.
I would recommend the KVO approach, as it is more flexible if you change your design later. Something along the lines of:

```
void *kAuthChangedContext = &kAuthChangedContext;

@implementation MyWindowController

- (void) awakeFromNib {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] addObserver:self 
        forKeyPath:@"UserAuthenticated" options:0 context:kAuthChangedContext];
}

- (void) updateViews {
    // Update your view state here
}

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
    change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if (kAuthChangedContext == context) {
        [self updateViews];
    }
    else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object
            change:change context:context];
    }
}

@end
```

Don't forget to remove yourself as an observer in the dealloc methods as well. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Francis for the confirmation that KVO is indeed the direction to take. Time to get stuck into learning more about KVC/KVO.

Comment: For future reference to myself/anyone else who might stumble across this, I've found this article: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/06/five-approaches-to-listening-observing.html that draws up some pros/cons for KVO vs Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a delegate for this or post a notification using the NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: Is implementing a delegate for this task the more common approach? I'm after teaching myself to do it the right way from the get go.